# Why are the html-tags inside <noscript> shown as text

Tags: php, html, noscript

I have a noscript part:

```
<noscript>
  <h1><?php echo $php_title; ?></h1>
  <div><?php echo $php_abstract; ?></div>
</noscript>
```

When I try this in a .html file (with the php tags removed, of course) it works as expected, but when in a .php file I get this visible output in the browser (i.e. the  is not treated as an html tag):

```
<h1>Stephen Porges "The Polyvagal Theory"</h1>
```

I do not set any special headers with PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$url = "https://api.zotero.org/groups/56508/items/3B6TR25A?format=atom&content=json";
$r = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

$r->setConfig(array(
    'ssl_verify_peer'   => FALSE,
    'ssl_verify_host'   => FALSE
));
try {
    $response = $r->send();
    if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
            $body = $response->getBody();
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($body);
            $php_content = $xml->content;
            $php_json = json_decode($php_content);
            $php_title = $php_json->title;
            $php_abstract = $php_json->abstractNote;
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

The document is returned as `text/html` according to the browser.

I use Chrome and there is maybe a bug here, but it seems strange that it works ok in .html but not .php if that is the reason.

Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Need more input. Show the PHP script that outputs the noscript.

Comment: Worked for me `<?php

$php_title = "TITLE HERE";

$php_abstract = "ABSTRACT";

?>

<noscript>
  <h1><?php echo $php_title; ?></h1>
  <div><?php echo $php_abstract; ?></div>
</noscript>` --- HTML source `<noscript>
  <h1>TITLE HERE</h1>
  <div>ABSTRACT</div>
</noscript>`

Comment: Are you sure PHP's running and/or your code resembles what I posted above? Kind of a silly question, but I have to ask.

Comment: Make sure to use htmlentities as well   `htmlentities($php_title);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, yes, I am sure the PHP runs as expected. Everything works ok until I turn off javascript in the browser.

Comment: @EasyBB tHere are no special chars involved. Or... testing. - No, that was not the problem. :-(

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Added the PHP code. It is actually all the PHP code (except for some display of variables further on).

Comment: Could those voting for closing please step forward and explain?

Comment: @EasyBB With this url: `http://ourcomments.org/cgi-bin/zformat.php?zk=3B6TR25A&zgi=56508` (and then of course with/without javascript turned on, in Chrome)

Comment: You're welcome. My comment above was done with JS turned off.

Comment: Ok so its live on a server. Thats what I was wondering ive had the slip where I opened it from dw or np++ and its all text well its because it's local without wamp or xampp lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with chrome where it is not rendered the *first time* the browser loads the page with JavaScript disabled.  If you refresh the page after it shows plain text, it should be rendered properly.

This issue has already been reported:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=235158

One person from that website suggested a workaround of using something like:

```
<div id="noscript">What was in the noscript-tag ..... </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('noscript').style.display="none";
     // rest of script
</script>
```

Therefore, it would only hide the elements if JavaScript is enabled.

I wouldn't say that it is that big of a deal.  For example, Stack Overflow uses `<noscript>` tags regardless and the same occurs.

Comment: Interesting info, thanks. But I’d rather stay away from the proposed workaround, as it might change what other clients (f.e. search engines) make of the content as well, if `noscript` is replaced with a generic div that doesn’t have the same special meaning. And especially considering the circumstances under which this bug occurs, I don’t think it is even that relevant – I’d assume users rather seldom disable JS while being on a site already, it is either on or off before already in most cases. And the handful of Chrome users with different habits should be used to strange effects already …

Comment: @CBroe I completely agree.  I just showed it as a possible alternative in case they found it to be a very big deal.

Comment: Thanks Anonymous, yes, it is a cache bug, but it does not help to reload the page (not with C-F5 either). I noticed it still ran some javascript even though it was disabled. Not sure what Chrome is doing there, but the Network panel said something in the Initiator column about JavaScript in the first row. Quite strange (bugs often are strange ;-) )

Comment: If it actually ran some JavaScript, that is indeed strange.  That doesn't really make much sense unless there is some huge bug.

Comment: I did some retesting. It saw this in the first row of the Initiator column: "VM12123 zformat.js:337 Script". However that seems be depend on that I had "Pause on exceptions" turned on. Still without that C-F5 did not fix the problem. However the second C-F5 fixed it. After that the display is correct.

Comment: Oh, perfect.  By "the display is correct," do you mean it loads correctly even the first time or it just behaves as normally?

Comment: When I turn off javascript and reloads with C-F5 the display is incorrect. The second C-F5 fixes it. (So that seems to be in accordance with what you said. Maybe the cache is not involved? That is up to the Chrome developers to check. ;-) )